# How can I reposition this div and still have it animate?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to modify this menu for my own use.https://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/249/index.html

I need it to look like this [image]
I am finding it impossible to get the positioning correct, the glowing bar needs to go at the bottom like in the pic and the drop down needs to go below that and expand outward (maybe a change to onclick event?).

The `Div lavalamp` in my HTML is the glowing bar and the menu code is at the end of the CSS file. I have tried moving the Div "lavalamp" just under my ul and when I do this it appears in the right position but the animation fails to work.

**Code**

```
https://jsfiddle.net/cs6jdfso/
```

Comment: Can you create a codepen for this problem?

Comment: Please provide the actual code, if that site goes down, this question can't help others in the future.

Comment: Updated with code, I am not sure how to update it with images so you can see the full effect.